# T-SQL: Joining two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I came across this problem and after going around and around I ended up getting stuck. I have two tables with some columns in common and I would like to merge them into one:

[image]

I am not looking for the code necessarily but rather for some guidance towards the answer.

Comment: please post expected result,actual result as text,not images

Comment: Question updated

Comment: `UNION ALL` is a good start. Then you need aggregates to combine rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your desired result by `full join-ing` both tables and using `coalesce` and `case` as below.

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.user1, t2.user1) AS "User", 
       t1.monday, 
       CASE 
         WHEN t2.tuesday = t1.monday THEN NULL 
         ELSE t2.tuesday 
       END as Tuesday
FROM   table1 t1 
       FULL JOIN table2 t2 
              ON t1.user1 = t2.user1 
ORDER  BY "user";
```

**Result:**

```
User    monday  Tuesday
----------------------
user1     gym     run
user1     run     
user2     gym     run
user3             gym
user4             gym
user5     gym
```

You can heck the demo **[here](http://rextester.com/MINA35727)**

Comment: That really helped a lot, but there is an issue: When user1 has run and gym on Mondays and Tuesdays, one of the exercises for Tuesday gets deleted by the CASE. If the case is removed then I duplicated rows.

Comment: @aeroalpha:  I worked through the sample data provided in question. If you are looking for an answer for a different data set, kindly add another question. we will be happy to help. Thanks  :-)